# Fragment vs View

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-view

Есть задача сделать активити с табами. В каждом табе будет разное содержимое: списки, карточки и т.д.

Меня интересует, что предпочтительней использовать и какими критериями надо руководствоваться при выборе с чем работать: фрагментами, и использовать для них `ViewPager` + `FragmentPagerAdapter`, или  использовать `View` и с ними `ViewPager` + `PagerAdapter`.

Я начал с фрагментов, но как мне показалось работать с ними несколько сложнее чем с обычным `View`.

**Из комментариев:**
Нужно сделать что-то похожее на экран звонилки.
Первая вкладка - список контактов, вторая - список входящих звонков, третья - список исходящих звонков, четвертая - карточки (для быстрого набора).

Comment: На ваш вопрос нет правильного ответа, т. к. он зависит от личного мнения. И от конкретной задачи, которую вы не приводите.

Comment: @metalurgus задача сделать что то  похожее на экран звонилки. Первая вкладка список контактов, вторая - список входящих звонков, третья - список исходящих, четвертая - карточки( типа как для быстрого набора )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В докумкентации к `FragmentPagerAdapter` написано:

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state.

В двух словах, это для случаев если у есть переиспользыемые компоненты (в виде фрагментаов) и малое количество табов.

В вашем случае, можно спокойно и `PagerAdapter` обойтись, если списки сделать через `RecyclerView`.